# Installing Google Chrome on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, yum, google-chrome

I am trying to install the latest version of Google Chrome on Amazon Linux using yum.

As far as I can tell Amazon Linux is based on RHEL/Centos however, it doesn't look like Google support this directly anymore.

I followed the instructions from http://www.raywaresoftware.com/10/using_yum_to_install_google_chrome/ however, when it comes to installing using the command

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
```

This command outputs the errors

Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-44.0.2403.157-1.x86_64 (google-chrome) Requires: libXss.so.1()(64bit)

Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-44.0.2403.157-1.x86_64 (google-chrome) Requires: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)

I have tried to install libXss using the command

```
yum install libXScrnSaver
```

However, I get the message:

2498 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package libXScrnSaver available.
Error: Nothing to do

How can I install the missing packages?

I am now stuck because we need to install Chrome on a server to run headless UI tests via Xvfb but we cannot get Chrome onto the server.

Thanks

Comment: For a myriad of reasons (including this one), I recommend that people stay far away from Amazon Linux. Just stick with a widely-used and widely-supported distro. If you want a RHEL derivative, go with CentOS.

Comment: Amazon Linux forked from CentOS **5**, several years ago, and bears little resemblance to it now. It is _not_ compatible and it is _not_ stable. Run away.

Answer (score 1):

There is an AWS Forums thread detailing how to do this at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229187

Also, there is a more recent blog at https://medium.com/@davidkadlec/installing-google-chrome-on-amazon-linux-ec2-d1cb6aa37f28

Comment: David, generally Server Fault asks that answers contain the required information, rather than just links. Links stop working fairly regularly, in which case the answer isn't useful.